# Tikz - difference between foreach and foreachitem

Tags: tikz-pgf

This might be a basic question, but I'm confused about the differences between foreach and foreachitem. Both are used on [tikz.net/neural_networks under the chapter Full-Code](https://tikz.net/neural_networks/).

I would like to adapt the code a little bit but therefore, I need the a similar variable like count= in foreach for foreachitem.

For me its not clear why foreachitem don't have the option count. Is there a workaround, because the conversion form foreachitem to foreach doesn't work.

Comment: Have you searched in this forum? https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=neural+network

Answer (score 1):

I found a suitable workaround for me. But still, I'm confused about the difference. And there isn't any documentation on https://tikz.dev about foreachitem.

With the tikz package `math` it is possible to create own variable which can be used to increment and in `\ifnum` statements.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

...
\readlist\Nnod{3,5,5,5,1} % array of number of nodes per layer
      
\tikzmath{
   integer \nn, nnlast;
   \nn = 0; } 

\foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{ % loop over layers
   \tikzmath{\nn = \nn + 1; } 
    ...
    \ifnum \nn =1
       ...
    \fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: The macros readlist and foreachitem aren't part of TikZ but the listofitems package. Why not simply use `\foreach \N in {3, 5, 5, 5, 1}`? By the way, LaTeX comes with its own integers: counters.

Comment: I tried your approach, but than the rest of the tikzpicture at Link (https://tikz.net/neural_networks/) didn't worked And I haven't the experience to change it. In general I find Latex and Tikz are not easy to learn. But every workaround brings you also a step further. Sometimes it just has to work and don't need to be pretty.